# Cauchy Sequence in R3 space

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $p_n$ = $(x_n,y_n,z_n)\in R^3$. Show that if ${(p_n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence using metric

$$d(p_j,p_k)=√{(x_j−x_k)^2+(y_j−y_k)^2+(z_j−z_k)^2}$$

then, so are the sequences $(x_n), (y_n), (z_n)$ using the metric

$$d(x_j,x_k) = |x_j-x_k|$$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: If you know the length of a vector, how large can each component be in absolute value?

Comment: It is square root of $x^2$ for a vector x. right?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $|x_i - x_j| = \sqrt{(x_i - x_j)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2 + (z_i - z_j)^2 } = d(p_i, p_j) <\epsilon$

Comment: Hi, can you please explain,why $x_n$ is less than $p_n$. Can you please give a clear explanation.

Comment: I never mentioned that $x_n$ is less than $p_n$. $x_n$ is a real number, while $p_n\in\mathbb{R}^3$ so there is no way of comparing them. However, I showed above that $d(x_i,x_j)<d(p_i,p_j)$ for every $i,j\in\mathbb N$. What's your specific doubt?

Comment: Well, i get that. But, how then it proves that, $x_n, y_n, z_n  $ using the metric $d(x_i,x_j)$? My question was if that $p_n $ is a cauchy seqeunce. then they use $d(x_i,x_j)$ metric.

Comment: What's the definition of a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$?

Comment: for  $\epsilon> 0$, we can find N > 0 so that $d(x_n, x_m) <\epsilon $ whenever
m > n ≥ N.

Comment: Right. The sketch of the proof you're looking for will look like: For a fixed $\epsilon >0$, since $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequences there is a $N$ such that.... hence for $i,j >N$ we have that $d(x_i,x_j)<\epsilon$